# (Angular) Saving each *ngFor element's ID to global array

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this *ngFor list, which is getting its elements from my db (postgres). I'm doing it like this:

```
    <div id="table" *ngFor="let data of User">
            <mat-checkbox color=primary checked=checked (click)="select(data.id)" >
                <div>{{data.name}}</div>
            </mat-checkbox>
            <mat-slide-toggle color=primary checked=checked>Ativo</mat-slide-toggle>
    </div>
```

This *ngFor is inside a form, which uses the (submit) anchor.

As you can see, when i load this page, all my checkboxes come marked. The thing is, when i hit the button 'SAVE', i need to send to my API an Array with all the 'data.id' that where left checked. This is how it looks:

[image]

I created this method called 'select', when i click any of my checkboxes, it selects (duh) that specific 'data.id' and storing it on my component.ts, but the thing is, what if i dont click a checkbox? Its 'data.id' is never stored, and if i just show all the elements with unselected checkoxes, what happens if i click to check, and uncheck the same element? The 'data.id' would already be stored, and destroying it would be quite unpleasant. Either way, it does not work.

So, when hitting the 'SAVE' button, i need to see which are checked (maybe with jquery), THEN get the checked's IDs (data.id). Is there any practical way to do this?

Comment: Hmm ... looking at this code .. some things pops in my mind .. first <div id="table" *ngFor="let data of User"> .. this wil create multiple <div id='table'> elements because you set the ngfor on that element

Comment: That's just for CSS :/ What i need is to see who's checked when clicking 'save'

Comment: second .. I would slice it up into 2 components. One (the parent) holds all the items, then with ngfor you pass the item to the "item" component (child). Then you have more control of an item (the child logic and html). The parent should (not sure about this one, will actually test it later), have 2 waybinding with it childs components, so the items array in the parent component is updated.

Comment: Maybe this helps to clarify more? https://medium.com/@fransyozef/angular-dashboard-starterkit-template-cruding-it-8a87080bb01